# Como colocar este alert JS para aparecer ao entrar na página

Tags: javascript, html

Galera, encontrei este [alert personalizado](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/) num site, e estou querendo colocar ele na minha página, para ao entrar na página, aparecer o alert.

Não consegui seguir a instrução do site, porquê no exemplo deles está para aparecer ao clicar num botão, e não entendo nada de Javascript.

Vou querer usar o segundo exemplo:

```
swal("Here's the title!", "...and here's the text!");
```

Alguém poderia fazer um modelo como resposta para mim colocar em minha página, obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer isso é adicionando esta biblioteca no HTML e usar de forma global.

Veja:

```js
swal("Meu alerta", "Olá alerta :D !");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

Segui as [instruções do guia](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/).

Comment: eu fiz isso e nao está funcionando, acho que tem algo errado com meu html kkk, ou a ordem que estou colocando os itens, to colocando tudo dentro da head

Comment: Como esta o seu HTML?

Comment: coloquei lá no final, depois do footer o codigo javascript e funcionou kkk. 
obrigado men,quando eu estava colocando na head nao funcionava.

Answer (score 0):

Veja esse exemplo: É simples! Agora é só você personalizar com as suas informações.

https://jsfiddle.net/v0tnfu1h/1/

Answer (score 0):

Como faz pra add um alerta quando zerar os números?

```
<button id="bcen" onclick="this.textContent --;" value="10000">10000</button>
<script>
document.getElementById("bcen").style.align = "center"; // Center
document.getElementById("bcen").style.width =
"300px"; //Size
document.getElementById("bcen").style.align = "center"; // Center
document.getElementById("bcen").style.height =
"200px"; //Size
</script>
```